# Cancel cURL request with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to cancel an already started cURL request with PHP. Since I have struggeled finding a good solution I am stuck now with an unlink function that does infact not work since cURL is downloading the content.

```
unlink(/foobar/foo.txt): Resource temporarily unavailable in /project/delete.php on line 16
```

This code is where I am stuck now:

```
unlink($fileLocation);
```

Since I am not experienced with cURL I am not sure how I can manage to stop the cURL request that is done in my downloading part:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

What basically is the usecase: A user downloads a file and should also have the possibility to cancel the download. How can I manage to do that?

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible since it's a synchronous request.

Comment: In what condition do you want to stop the download?

Comment: @HtmHell it should work like a kill since I do not care about the status of the curl. I only want to kill curl, so I can manage to delete the file.

Comment: @D.Brader But in what condition you are trying to do that? If you want to stop the download / delete the file, why did you start to download it in the first place?

Comment: @HtmHell I have raised the PHP execution time, to allow longer downloads. But if a user does not want to wait that long and rather download a shorter version (maybe zipped or sth like that), he can cancle the download. The usecase is that a user wants to stop his download because only 1 download per user at the time is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are running the download script as a daemon, you can use `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` option: (otherwise, you can just abort the request by leaving the page or abort the xhr)

As mentioned in the docs:

> Return a non-zero value to abort the transfer. In which case, the
>   transfer will set a CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK error.

So you can use a callback function that will constanly check if a database value is set to true, and if so - return 1 which will abort the curl.

Then when your user clicks the "cancel" button you should update the database and set that value to true.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progressCallback');

curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch) === CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK) {
    // Callback aborted
}

function shouldAbortDownload()
{
    // Check the database if should abort the download.
}

function progressCallback($ch, $download_size = 0, $downloaded = 0, $upload_size = 0, $uploaded = 0)
{
    static $lastCheckTime = 0;

    if ((time() - $lastCheckTime) > 4)
        if (shouldAbortDownload()) {
            return 1;
        }

        $lastCheckTime = time();
    }
}
```

Comment: ... that sleep(5) thing is probably a terrible idea, it will stop the download each time MIN(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE , OS_MAX_BUFSIZE) has been reached, which will probably happen much faster than sleep(5), so when you're downloading big files, this will probably make the download muuuuch slower. and when you're downloading small files, the sleep(5) will make it stall for 5 seconds, even if the file was just downloaded in 1 second.  a much better approach would be `static $lastCheckTime=0; if((time() - $lastCheckTime) > 4 && shouldAbortDownload()){ return 1;} $lastCheckTime=time();`

Comment: @HtmHell now you forgot to declare $lastCheckTime as a static variable, so that code still does not work, it will check every time. (because $lastCheckTime is not saved between invocations, it is reset to NULL on every call)

Comment: @HtmHell now it's declared outside of the function's variable scope, so inside the function, that variable can't be reached, and it will be treated like a brand new variable with NULL on every invocation. it has to be declared as a static variable inside the function, not outside.

Comment: @hanshenrik Updated, I declared this as a global variable inisde the function

Comment: @HtmHell that is also a bad idea, now it puts junk in the global namespace for no good reason. what if some other code also decide to make a global $lastCheckTime? try this instead: http://paste.debian.net/plain/1033008  - inside functions, the `static` keyword is a storage specifier, meaning `this value should only be initialized once (to 0 in this case), and the value should be retained in between calls.`  (meanwhile, confusingly, `static` has different meanings in classes/objects -.-)

Comment: @hanshenrik I only knew what `static` does in classes, and indeed I got confused how you wanted me to use it. Now I understand, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This  [First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51223901/6868482) answer is perfect. But it works only with original callback function.
It don't work if you insert your arg into callback function, for example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,function ($resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size) use ($my_arg) 
  {
    progressCallback($resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size,       $uploaded_size, $my_arg);   
  }
);
```

and handle callback

```
function progressCallback($resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size, $my_arg) {
   //some logic 
  if ($need_to_cancel) { 
    return 1;
  }
}
```